# Problem in ./startFabric.sh: Error response from daemon: Container is not running

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been using hyperledger composer for a long time. I have installed hyperledger composer on a new machine but on the command ./startFabric.sh it is ending with the following error

```
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'startFabric.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv12
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)
Stopping orderer.example.com ... done
Stopping couchdb ... done
Stopping ca.org1.example.com ... done
Removing peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Removing orderer.example.com ... done
Removing couchdb ... done
Removing ca.org1.example.com ... done
Removing network composer_default
Creating network "composer_default" with the default driver
Creating ca.org1.example.com ... 
Creating couchdb ... 
Creating orderer.example.com ... 
Creating orderer.example.com
Creating ca.org1.example.com
Creating orderer.example.com ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... 
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
sleeping for 15 seconds to wait for fabric to complete start up
Error response from daemon: Container abf272793595d47750a9b3ab8f381f183f64bcdf3b9c21fba00bef6de6517060 is not running
```

This command is running fine on older machine but on new machine it is giving this error I have installed it by following the link https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-index

Please help... I am seriously tired of this. I have also tried solutions on web nothing helped...

Comment: Hyperledger Composer is no longer actively developed or maintained.  It's likely that compose file / setup in incompatible with your new host system.  You can try running `docker ps -a` and see if any containers failed to start

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue too. after searching all different answers in stackoverflow , i finally managed to find one that works for me .. all thanks to the contributor .

below is the step :
to solve this issue. Needed to add below line under environment: in docker-compose.yaml file for orderer and peer containers in your hlfv12 script subdir.

```
- GODEBUG=netdns=go
```

Hope this work for you too .